# creating a database with dynamic fields

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-design, dynamic-data

I have database to be designed about people info

there will be some common details about people like name,age,address,contact etc...

but there are categories of people like government servants,business man,salaried , politicians etc...

so there will be some dynamic fields about the categories...

common details table can be made easily but the problem is with dynamic fields of categories like
government servants will have income, dept, since,etc...

I have created three tables :

Peoples Table: name, age, DOB, etc...
Category:rows for Government servants, salaried etc...
Attributes:

```
------------------------
ID|Category|Field|Value
-----------------------
1 |GS      |dept |electricity
```

the above database design (what i am using now) is kind of 
[NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx) database deign with
`Nop_Customer` and `Nop_CustomerAttribute` table

**so is this a good one or anything better than this could be done:** (for this situation)

Two imp points to be considered:
1-users will add data for this so controls will have to be created accordingly
2- this database will be searched by others.

**EDIT:**

The fields for each Category will be fixed.

but the categories will be added over time not by users but by developers, so need it be less hectic and maintainable for developers

Comment: Is this extra data changing fairly often or is it set?  I ask because if the other fields are pretty much set based on the type of person then use real tables.  However, if you are providing a facility to extend those types (including adding additional ones) and need to do so without modifying your core tables then what you have is a good start.

Comment: See [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) on how such a "super flexible" approach might lead to disaster ....

Comment: @marc_s: I have quite a bit of experience building systems that deal with dynamic data such as this.  And yes, if you don't pay attention it could absolutely crater.  However, done correctly and for the right reasons the software can sing.

Comment: @RohitWagh: Given the update I wouldn't go with dynamic data and instead take Dan's approach below.  Your requirements don't seem to necessitate the coding complexity you would be adding.

Comment: @ChrisLively: *done correctly* - yes, that's really the whole point - it's not easy; it can be done, but you need to know and be aware what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make tables for each type of person.  In those tables, only store what is applicable.  If Phil Jones is a politician, then he would have an entry in the Person table that describes him as far as a person is concerned.  He would also have a row in the Politicians table that would describe him as far as a politician is concerned.  Make each of the child tables have a foreign key relationship with the person table's ID column.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to use an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) tool such as [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx):

> NHibernate is a mature, open source object-relational mapper for the
>   .NET framework. It's actively developed , fully featured and used in
>   thousands of successful projects.

You could then use OOP principals such as inheritance to have one super class covering the *basics* and then extend the class depending on what other extra features you need. [This](http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance) tutorial gives you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: This is a round about way of saying: use real tables instead of dynamic data.

Comment: @ChrisLively: I do not understand what you mean. I think that this manner would yield a similar result to what **Dan** is saying.

Comment: Use of any tool  does solve  not this problem of dynamic data. It needs  dynamic data structure that is a  collection of key value pairs. This can be  accomplished with in-row XML columns, Text arrays or sub tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML field so You can store unstructured data or use one of inheritance mappings
see here http://www.agiledata.org/essays/mappingObjects.html